# Updating php version project from 5.2.1 to 7

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I am changing my project from php version 5.2.1 to 7(new version), but the project is in codegnitor version 1.7.2, So i should change php version,mysql to mysqli . Should i change Codegnitor version also

Comment: No no need to change codeigniter version. You can upgrade your php version. codeigniter 1.7.2 will working ohk with php 7 so there will be no problem while updating from php 5.2.1 to php 7. But codeigniter 1.7.2 is also an old version so you have update codeigniter as well.

Comment: Yes you DO have to upgrade CodeIgniter as well; that's probably more important.

Comment: Whatever you do, stop using `mysql_*` functions

Comment: Thank you guys, i think its better to change the codegnitor version also....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not be needed since php is (mostly) backwards compatible. I would however recommend to do it anyway.